# Cocos2d-x fuzziness on win32

Tags: winapi, opengl, cocos2d-x

I'm use cocos2d-x on win32 platform, but get fuzzy frames by default settings. If CCTexture2D's _antialiasEnabled to false, will get the alias. How can i improve the frame quality? Others game's on win32, how to guarantee this? Thx for answer~~

Comment: Make sure you draw everything at scale of 1

Comment: That is the point, some texture that i need to scale/rotate it. So, some suggest??